# How to make a custom dataset for CNN using pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've started studying deep learning, but every tutos I've seen use pre-made datasets like cifar-10.
I'm currently trying to make a programme able to see if something is in an image or not.

For that, I've put two types of images :
-with the object in it
-without

following the tutos and courses I've had, I managed to do those :

````py
# imports
#...
def getDataFrame():
    filenames = os.listdir("charlies")
    categories = []
    for filename in filenames:
        category = filename.split('_')[0]
        if category == 'yes':
            categories.append(1)
        else:
            categories.append(0)

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'filename': filenames,
        'category': categories
    })
    ```
It does return what I want :
                          filename  category
0                  no_Resized1.jpg         0
1                         no_2.jpg         0
2                         no_3.jpg         0
3                       yes_16.jpg         1
4                       yes_31.jpg         1
5                       yes_33.jpg         1
6                       yes_34.jpg         1
7                       yes_35.jpg         1

In my CNN file, I try :
```python
if __name__ == "__main__":

    df = dc.getDataFrame()
    ds = customCharlieDataset(df)

    train_df, validate_df = train_test_split(ds, test_size=0.20, random_state=3)
    train_df = train_df.reset_index(drop=True)
    validate_df = validate_df.reset_index(drop=True)
````

but it return an error "    ds = customCharlieDataset(df)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"
witch, first I don't really understand, but I think it as something to do with applying trasforms.toTensor() that I call in my customDataset Class.
Here's the code in case it helps:

```py
class customDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.dataframe = dataframe

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataframe)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        row = self.dataframe.iloc[index]
        transform = transforms.ToTensor()
        return (
            transform(Image.open(row["filename"])),
            row["category"]
        )
```

Can someone explain why is it not working, or how I should have done it?

Thank you for your help :)!

Comment: Show your imports. Most likely you import `df` somewhere

Comment: ```python
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import customDataset
import torch.nn as nn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import dataCreate as dc
```
df is the result of 
```
df = dc.getDataFrame()
```

Answer (score 0):

First (not the error but maybe you should edit that) `customCharlieDataset` is not defined, do you mean `customDataset`?
Secondly, the `Dataset` in `class customDataset(Dataset)` is `torch.utils.data.Dataset` right? Third, `__getitem__` should return two tensors, one for the input-sample and one for the target. `row["category"]` doesnt seem like a tensor to me, you should fix that.

You try to call which shouldnt work `transform = transforms.ToTensor()`.
Try just `torch.tensor(np.array(Image.open(row["filename"])))`

Comment: Hi thx for your answer

"First (not the error but maybe you should edit that) customCharlieDataset is not defined, do you mean customDataset?"

Yeah I was making change forgot to change that =)

Comment: "Secondly, the Dataset in class customDataset(Dataset) is torch.utils.data.Dataset right"
Yes it is, I import ```from torch.utils.data import Dataset```
"Third, __getitem__ should return two tensors, one for the input-sample and one for the target. row["category"]" 
Well that's how I found it in a tuto, so I should make it like 
```
        return (
             torch.tensor(Image.open(row["filename"])),
            torch.tensor(row["category"])
        )
```
?

Comment: you dont need the parantheses. It should be ```return torch.tensor(np.array(Image.open(row["filename"]))), torch.tensor(row["category"])```